# Selection area width

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with `<div style='width: 640px; margin: 0 auto'>` as a main block with no text content outside of it. How do I make selection not getting out of `<div>` area?

[image: Screenshot of how's it currently being selected]

The picture above illustrates how is it being selected by default.

So, how can I limit selection area width to width of `<div>`?

Comment: have you try this overflow: hidden;

Comment: I believe the selection area is default to the width of whatever you are selecting. Can you provide a screenshot of the chrome debugger showing the div selected? This would show the actual div width. (F12, Elements Tab, choose the div from the html then it will highlight it on the screen)

Comment: can you include an jsfiddle?!

Comment: @vesuvious http://i.imgur.com/e6BEHGT.png What is orange area though?

Comment: @MuhammadAli That worked! Thank you. How do I close the question, though, if there are no answers?

Comment: The orange area is your margin, if you look at the bottom right in the toolbar it will show the sizes as well as color information.

Comment: @nomicos: Add the answer yourself and mark it as the correct answer. That will leave it visible for posterity. Otherwise, you could delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `overflow: hidden` for `<div>` style.
Thanks to @MuhammadAli for answer.